# Hiding SSRS master page from output

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

Is there a way to avoid rendering the master page to Excel when exporting an SSRS report? The master page contains a sub report. The master page does not contain anything except the call to the subreport.

Comment: So what purpose does the "master page" serve then? Maybe there's a better way to do what you want.

Comment: I`m looping over many different codes, for each code I am producing a subreport.

Comment: Basically looking for a way to produce many reports through a master report instead of calling rs.exe from a batch. looking for a way not to render the master to excel (or hide it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to remove all objects from the Master report, apart from the subreport.  Then I would relocate the subreport to 0,0 i.e. the top left corner.  Then I would shrink the master report to the size of the subreport.